# Probabilistic Clause Choice

Tags: random, prolog

Its been a long time since I used Prolog in earnest, but I can't find any reference to this by googling, or in the texts I have. This may be a failure of terminology, so apologies if I massacre that.

If I have a program that could have multiple solutions:

```
likes(mary, joe).
likes(bob, joe).

:- likes(X, joe)
```

Is there a simple built-in way to have the solver run matching predicates in random order, and therefore give results in a random order (or, equivalently, have the first solution be random)?

Obviously you can get as sophisticated as you like with the word *random*. I'm thinking of some uniform random sampling from the set of valid predicates at each step of the solver. Something more complex like a uniform random sampling over valid *solutions* is also fine. The issue is general.

I can probably build a program to do this, using a random number generator, and meta-programming. But I want to check if I'm missing something simple.

Comment: You are not missing anything simple.  The order a Prolog engine tries the predicate's clauses is determined by the order they appear in the source, with special rules (involving a multifile directive) for a predicate with clauses in more than one source file, but nothing that would randomize things the way you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linear selection of matching clauses is an important part of Prolog algorithm (or better [SLD resolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SLD_resolution)) . And each match is a *candidate* solution. I think you cannot expect Prolog as such to randomize clauses order for you.

I would elaborate on mat' answer:

```
:- meta_predicate randomize_preds(0).

randomize_preds(C) :-
   findall(C, retract(C), Cs),
   random_permutation(Cs, Rs),
   maplist(assertz, Rs).

:- dynamic likes/2.

likes(alice, joe).
likes(bob, joe).
likes(charlie, joe).
likes(dan, joe).
```

test:

```
3 ?- randomize_preds(likes(_,_)),findall(X,likes(X,joe),L).
L = [bob, alice, charlie, dan].

4 ?- randomize_preds(likes(_,_)),findall(X,likes(X,joe),L).
L = [alice, bob, dan, charlie].
```

Answer (score 2):

Randomizing the *solutions* is easiest in this case, because you only have finitely many and can thus collect them easily:

```
?- findall(X, likes(X, joe), Ps0), random_permutation(Ps0, Ps), member(P, Ps).
```

This gives you all people `P` that like `joe`, one by one, in a random order.

Comment: But this doesn't scale. You need the full solution set to be tractable, which it likely isn't in a more real-world problem. As OP said, the issue is general.

Comment: This easily scales to millions of solutions, try for example: `?- time(findall(X, between(1, 5_000_000, X), Xs)).` (works within seconds), which surely covers many real-world problems where the solutions are described via such simple facts.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've been unclear here. What I meant to say is: a million solutions is nothing close to the combinatorial explosion you could expect from Prolog's expressive power. Here's a stupid example: generating {a random|the full list of} array of bits where the number of set bits is even.  For length 2N, there are 2^N of them.  The random algorithm he asks for would take time O(2N) to generate one; the `findall`/`random_permutation` algorithm would take O(2^N).

Comment: In cases where the number of solutions grows more than linearly with the number of clauses, I would write a simple meta-interpreter that dynamically selects a random clause at each inference step.

Comment: Yes, my problem domain is combinatorial, unfortunately. Which is why my intuition was that it had to randomize at the rules level, not the solutions. So, no simple solution. Thanks.

Comment: Well writing a meta-interpreter for a subset of Prolog isn't so bad, is it? It will probably take only a few clauses to cover many use cases. Good luck!